# Is there a way to programmatically enumerate Sonos shares on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, sharing

I am referring to music shares created by the Sonos Controller. http://www.sonos.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was just adding more music to my Sonos library and thought of this question. Turns out that on Mac, Sonos programmatically modifies `/etc/smb.conf` and adds share entires.

So to answer the question, the way to enumerate these would be to parse `/etc/smb.conf`, if you're running locally, or shell out to `smbclient` or use equivalent Samba library if running remotely.